# Set brand image on bootstrap navbar using link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Bootstrap uses this structure to set brand image:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="navbar-header">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
       <img alt="Brand" src="...">
     </a>
   </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

But im using a link_to tag and it actually works fine but with no image:

```
<%= link_to raw('CIFCO'), cr_clientes_path, :class=>'navbar-brand'%>
```

So, how do I turn that link to into the bootstrap structure to show brand image instead of text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `image_tag` inside `link_to` to display image

```
<%= link_to image_tag("your-image-name", alt: "Brand"), cr_clientes_path, :class=>'navbar-brand' %>
```

Comment: Ty! I will try it now!

Comment: It works, I mean it does insert the image but it doesnt fit at all, even if change my image size from an image editor, it still doesnt fit, im sure it needs some css adjustment to make it work, do you have any idea?

Comment: Was mb, I was aplying some css by mistake, just took it out and got it working just fine! Thank you!